# Class of a linear series in the Chow ring of $\operatorname{Sym}^d(C)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be curve of genus $g$, and $\lvert D \rvert$ a linear series on $C$, of degree $d$. We view $\lvert D \rvert$ as a subvariety of $\operatorname{Sym}^d(C) $. Macdonald [1] gave a simple formula for the class of $\lvert D \rvert$ in the cohomology ring $H^*(\operatorname{Sym}^d(C),\operatorname{Z} )$. Is there a known  formula for the class of $\lvert D \rvert$ in the Chow ring of $\operatorname{Sym}^d(C)$, possibly modulo algebraic equivalence?

[1] I.G. Macdonald, *Symmetric products of an algebraic curve.* Topology 1 (1962), 319-343.

Comment: Sounds interesting! Can I ask what is the formula in the cohomology ring?

Comment: If $\lvert D \rvert$ has dimension $r$, its class in $H^{2d-2r}(\operatorname{Sym}^d(C) )$ is the term of degree $2d-2r$ in $\ (1+\eta )^{d-r-g}e^{\theta }\,$, where $\eta $ is the class of $\operatorname{Sym}^{d-1}(C) +p\subset \operatorname{Sym}^d(C) $ and
$\theta $ is the pull back of the principal polarization of $JC$.

Comment: I have wondered about this in the basic case, where $C\subset \mathbb{P}^n$, embedded by a complete linear system as a degree $d$ curve. Is there a 'nice' description?

Comment: @Mohan: I don't think that this case is more basic... Anyway, I know nothing more in that case.

Comment: Collino wrote about the Chow ring of symmetric products of curves. His results seem similar to MacDonald’s but for Chow instead of cohomology. Maybe the formula could be extracted from his results here: https://www.projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-19/issue-4/The-rational-equivalence-ring-of-symmetric-products-of-curves/10.1215/ijm/1256050666.full

Comment: @Samir Canning: Thank you. I know Collino's paper, but so far I haven't been able to use it to answer my question.